# Array sum not printing in recursive function

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote a recursive function that returns the sum of the array when called. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>


struct array {
    int A[10];
    int size;
    int length;
};


void displayArray(struct array arr) {
    std::cout << "the elements are :-" << std:: endl << '\t';
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        std::cout << arr.A[i] << ',';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
}

int i = 0;
int sum(int* a, int length) {
    // Size of an int element.
    int j = 4;
    if (i < length) {
        return a[i+1] + sum((a + j), length);
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}



int main()
{
    struct array arr = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 10, 7};
    int* p;
    std::cout<< sum(&arr.A[0],arr.length );
}
```

However, it is not returning anything and also, I ran it on an online compiler. It is not showing any error or warning, but it's not showing any output either.

Comment: What do you expect `sum` to return when `i < length` isn't true?

Comment: Turn all compiler warnings on, and fix these 1st before asking here please!!

Comment: `int j = 4;` Why?

Comment: @Bob__ because I want to add the array, so i kept j as the size of int

Comment: @gratusrichard Don't change your question. Put in everything correctly first because changing the question might change the answer. And don't include commented code. If it's not necessary for the problem, then it shouldn't be included.

Comment: On top of the stackoverflow because `i` does not change at all you exceed the bounds of the array on the 3rd iteration because the `a` pointer advances by 4 elements each recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

well in this

```
int i = 0;
int sum(int* a, int length) {
    int j = 4;
   if (i < length) {
       //std::cout << a[i];
       return a[i] + sum((a + j), length);
   }
}
```

your exit condition is `i >= length`, but you never change `i` so this will keep recursing till you run out of stack space. Since this is a very strange function (I mean why is j = 4) I cant suggest a solution, only why it doesnt work at present

here is the error on my dev box

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF711A9297E in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000003E526B3FA8).
```

Comment: as I wrote my comment, i got the j=4 ... I think it assumes an sizeof(int) = 4

Answer (score 0):

You are running in an endless loop because of your if condition never reaching an end.
Besides this, the global i and the local j are both superflous.
Maybe it would be easier to use your length to access the array and as an end marker and decrease it with each call of sum

```
int sum(int* a, int length){
if (--length >= 0) 
    return a[length] + sum(a, length); 
else 
    return 0; 
}
```

by the way, I would recommend using

```
`std::array <int, 10> a= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};'
```

instead of  your struct including int A[10];

this gives you out of bounds checking, iterators for your collection, no need for C pointer algorithmics, ...